# How to load jQuery content into div from external content specific div

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, attr

New to jQuery.

I've got two lines of code.

```
$("#proj_content").load("/projects/rest #proj_cont");
$("#proj_content").load(jQuery(this).attr("class"));
```

The first does the job perfectly. I want to load the directory "projects/rest" and only the content from the div #proj_cont

The second allows me to make this dynamic through a CMS but I can't figure out how to get the `#proj_cont` in there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I believe what I need is something close to this:

```
$("#proj_content").load($(this).attr("class") " + #proj_cont "); –
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` toolbar to format code, so I don't have to edit your question each time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ordinary string concatenation:

```
$("#proj_content").load("/projects/rest #" + $(this).attr("class"));
```

or maybe you meant:

```
$("#proj_content").load("/projects/" + $(this).attr("class") + " #proj_cont");
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I think what i need is close to this.  Any help? Thanks!  $("#proj_content").load($(this).attr("class") " + #proj_cont ");